# Progress Database 4GL

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

Does anyone know where I can get some samples/resources on 4GL language for Progress Database OTHER THAN THE PROGRESS DATABASE WEBSITE?

Thanks

Comment: The 'openedge' tag on stack overflow? :) Seriously. There are a few people that hang out here and answer questions. They know their stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a copy of the 4GL handbook from the Progress website.

http://www.progress.com/progress/products/documentation/docs/dvhbk/dvhbk.pdf

Answer (score 2):

http://www.peg.com

http://www.oehive.org

http://www.progresstalk.com

http://www.psdn.com (maintained by Progress Software)

Comment: I saw these. What I am lookig for is lots of samples in the 4GL language.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of samples do you exactly need? If you want to improve 4GL skills, then 4GL Handbook is a very nice way to get known to the language, it comes with Progress Documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I found several reference books for Progress, ProDatasets, etc. on [Scribd](http://scribd.com) which I went to when the links on the Progress official communities were broken.